# Issue with appmetrics-dash module while using node:8-alpine docker file

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

This is the error below i am getting while executing my node app inside a docker container with the base image as node:8-alpine

```
throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'appmetrics-dash'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/proxyapp/proxyapp.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Comment: We need a bit more informations to help you. Maybe you can post your node-code and/or your dockerfile contents. Maybe this is the same issue as you run in: https://github.com/RuntimeTools/appmetrics/issues/539#issuecomment-418074861

Answer (score 0):

Alpine linux was not a supported platform: 
https://github.com/RuntimeTools/appmetrics-dash/issues/139

But their team is working now about it https://github.com/RuntimeTools/appmetrics/issues/582